# Automatically connect subdomains to directories in apache

Tags: apache-2.2

Where I work (a webdev company) we have a testing server with a peculiar setup. Which is that requesting

```
foo.myusername.thisserver.com
```

will automatically send you to the files located at

```
/home/myusername/foo/web
```

on that server. Just creating a new dir in the homedir is enough. No need to edit Apache config or even reboot it. This is very convenient for developing. You just have to check a project out from SVN and you're good to go (most of the time).

I was wondering, how is this done?

Also, if at all possible, I'd like it so that I can override the webroot by editing a file in the app's dir (/home/myusername/foo in this case), for example setting it to

```
/home/myusername/foo/somedir/webroot
```

But I don't know how flexible Apache config is in this regard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`mod_vhost_alias`** — http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html