# Dynamic Virtual Hosts In Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

My httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/www/foo/htdocs"
ServerName foo
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/www/bar/htdocs"
ServerName bar
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/www/baz/htdocs"
ServerName baz
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice the pattern? Is there any way to cut down on the duplication, or am I stuck with having a separate VirtualHost entry for each site?

Comment: duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/6920/automatically-connect-subdomains-to-directories-in-apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it after reading Dark Ninja's answer. Here's what my httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like now.

```
# Dynamic virtual hosts.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/%0/htdocs/
```

I also had to enable mod_vhost_alias by uncommenting this line in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

Comment: Just be aware that using `VirtualDocumentRoot` actually impacts `mod_rewrite` rules (as used in WordPress, Drupal and many PHP frameworks). It requires you to apply a `RewriteBase` rule to each app. I'm still trying to figure out a workaround to that.

Comment: Make sure to verify that both www.domain.com & domain.com work.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you have a look at the Apache website for dynamic virtual hosts.  The other methods require a restart of the Apache server.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two very different answers.

1. Use the "subdomain-as-account-folder"trick.
2. Write a short script and configuration file that together generate your httpd-vhosts.conf file(s) dynamically.  Then the script and configuration become your masters, and the .conf files are "expendable."

I recommend #2, and I think the Pragmatic Programmers might as well.

Comment: I think #2 will require restarting httpd service though?

Comment: @James A. Rosen - can you show us how you configured this and in which file?